# Stack (Overflow|Answers)

Tags: discussion, plagiarism, copycat-sites

To be clear, I'm aware of the proper procedure for reporting SCRAPERs, but I found it more pertinent to put it here as there was a lot of information I wished to articulate about the site and it didn't seem right to put all of it in the contact form.

---

So, I've found I particularly egregious SCRAPER called Stack Answers (I'd provide a link to their main page, but I don't want to give them any more visits than I already have).

Here's the site description:

> [Stack Answers] is a site for Questions & Answers for professional and enthusiast programmers related to: java, android, php, c#, javascript, jquery, python, ios, c++, html, css, mysql, asp.net, objective c, sql, iphone, ruby on rails, .net, c, asp.net mvc, xml, r, json, ruby, wpf, ajax, angularjs, linux, django, sql server, html5, google maps, arrays, wordpress, node.js, eclipse, xcode, multithreading, regex, laravel, spring, vb.net, database, image, windows, mongodb, forms, facebook, apache, oracle and more...
>   It's 100% free, no registration required.

Sound familiar?

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

It's a fairly large site, so I was surprised that I couldn't find any reports of it (if it's been dealt with before, please say so).

Examples of plagiarized content:

- [Non-public API usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369633/non-public-selectors-in-payload) **->** http://stackanswers.com/questions/26369633/non-public-selectors-in-payload

  - This was the one that brought the site to my attention: it was third in the results of a Google search where the original Stack Overflow question was #1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455836/openshift-decodes-url-before-reaching-node-js-server **->** http://stackanswers.com/questions/26455836/openshift-decodes-url-before-reaching-node-js-server
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455842/i-dont-understand-rspec **->** http://stackanswers.com/questions/26455842/i-dont-understand-rspec

(If you want a bit of humor, look in the source of this post and you'll see that the URLs are exactly the same (including post ID), with the exception of "overflow" being changed to "answers.")

You could, of course, also just go to their home page, click on any question, and Google its body to find the corresponding SO question (that's how I found the latter two in that list).

Alternatively, go to any question and change "overflow" to "answers" in the URL (it's very fast: you could even go to the [realtime page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest) and use the most recent question).

They provide no attribution (as far as I can tell) in the form of any author or link back to Stack Overflow, and it is quite heavy on the ads, so they're presumably making quite a bit of dough with this blatant plagiarism.

Comment: @brasofilo I would have used the Contact Us procedure, but there seemed to be too much information to include there.

Comment: np, just signaling the procedure, if others don't feel it should be closed as dup, ok

Comment: Well... actually there is a "Source: Stackoverflow" link underneath the comments section and it mentions and links to the Creative Commons Attribution license at the bottom of the page.

Comment: They have at least [one sister site](http://how360.org/) scraping from other SE sites.

Comment: The SO source link actually links to the original question, so the attribution part might be considered okay... but it's not a straight link, it goes through an ad-heavy link shortener...

Comment: @SztupY AFAIK CC-SA allows the use for commercial goals as long as attribution is given, so the ads doesn't really change anything as long as the attribution is OK.

Comment: Took me a while to find the SO link as it's not visible when AdBlock for Chrome is running. Not sure if they remove it when ad blocking is detected though, as they do hide the answers.

Comment: @ivarni based on [(3) here](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/4.0/Attribution_and_marking#Questions_about_attribution.2Fmarking_in_4.0) I'm not yet sure whether link shorteners acutally satisfy the attribution criteria for 4.0 CC. I couldn't find any human readable discussion about shorteners for cc-by-sa 3.0

Comment: @NobuGames That might change things a bit, but if I recall correctly, there's something in the license that requires direct attribution to the authors if directly quoting (which it is). It *does* list an author, but it's hidden toward the bottom (as is the source link). Even if not, the entire site itself seems a bit sketchy and unethical, so perhaps it might be good for SE to have a chat with them. It seems like they're doing the bare minimum to comply with the license.

Comment: as of 13 april 2015 I have an adf.ly page linking me to wikisugar. what is this?

Comment: @interwebz The Stack Exchange team informed me that they dealt with Stack Answers accordingly; it appears that they have found a new revenue source.

Comment: well im happy that they did, and im sad that they got rev still.. p.s. how do they 'deal with it'? (i know they put on sunglasses, anything else?)